# How display marginal labels on bibliography entries with showlabels?

Tags: showkeys, showlabels

How can I cause marginal labels to appear for entries in the printed bibliography if I am using the `showlabels` package?  (Note that I mean labels in the margin rather than the numbers or names, etc., that are printed within the bibliography.)

(I'm *not* asking about causing labels to appear where `\cite` commands appear in the text.)

With the `showkeys` package instead of `showlabels`, they appear automatically.

**ADDED**

If I merely load the `showlabels` package and include a `\showlabels{bibitem}`, that will *not* produce labels for the actual items in the References section (although it will produce labels at the various `\cite` locations). For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{short.bib}
@book{Doe2016,
  author = {Doe, Jane},
  title = {Theory of everything},
  publisher = {YourBooks},
  year = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[names,dvipsnames,named]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{showlabels}
\renewcommand{\showlabelfont}{\small\color{blue}}
\showlabels[\small\color{gray}]{cite}
\showlabels[\small\color{red}]{bibitem}

\addbibresource{short}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:one}

Look at Section~\ref{sec:one} for more information. Read more about it in Doe~\cite{Doe2016}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: No label shown on bibliography entry]

Comment: Remove the solution from the current question and add it as a self-answer which you can accept. Self-answers are welcome here. Perhaps consider also including a minimal example with some images. That will make the content more readily consumable to future visitors.

Comment: note `\usepackage{show labels}` should be `\usepackage{showlabels}` (the space is ignored only by accident, and the package name has no space)

Comment: @David Carlisle: the space in `show labels` was, alas, an artifact of the OS X's autocorrection that is sometimes very stubborn.

Comment: ah, I'm a bit sensitive to that as a lifetime ago I added some code so the space around commas in `\usepackage{a , b , c}` were ignored, but as a side effect it ignores all space and people manage to take advantage of that in exotic ways that were not planned:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package author, Norman Gray, provided a [solution](https://bitbucket.org/nxg/showlabels/issues/10/labels-for-biblatex-bibliography-entries):

```
\makeatletter
\showlabels{blx@bibitem}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

Because i don't directly see `\bibitem` in the source when I'm using `bibtex`, I had not realized that the same sort of `\showlabels` command that is documented to work with `cite` will also handle `\bibitem`(once `bibtex` is used to create the `.bbl` file).

**Added:** However, the labels on items within the actual References list no longer appear if one uses an external `.bib` file. (See addendum to my original post for example.)

Here's an example that illustrates using `\showlabels{bibitem}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[names,dvipsnames,named]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{showlabels}
\renewcommand{\showlabelfont}{\small\color{blue}}
\showlabels[\small\color{gray}]{cite}
\showlabels[\small\color{red}]{bibitem}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:one}

Look at Section~\ref{sec:one} for more information. Read more about it in Doe~\cite{Doe2016}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Doe2016}
Jane Doe, \emph{Theory of everything}, YourBooks, Somewhere, 2016.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Using biblatex, `\showlabels{bibitem}` does not seem to work.

Comment: @jpmath: You are correct in that `\showlabels{bib item}` no longer produces labels within the actual "References" list if one uses an external `.bib` file. I'm removing my acceptance on my answer!